# VBA Webbrowser Button Click for Automation

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, automation, getelementsbyname

The lines below are a full code.

[Problem]
VBA Form displays Google and enter the value of "best radio" and clicks the button. 
1) But 438 error shows up after a successful Google page with "best radio" entered.
2) 'Google Search' button is clicked, but only if I press the enter key, the Google shows the search result.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objIE
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Top = 0
objIE.Left = 0
objIE.Width = 800
objIE.Height = 600
objIE.Addressbar = 0
objIE.StatusBar = 0
objIE.Toolbar = 0
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.Navigate ("http://www.google.com")

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4
     objIE.Document.GetElementByID("lst-ib").Value = "best radio"
     objIE.Document.GetElementsByName("btnK").Click
     SendKeys "{ENTER}"


Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4
MsgBox "complete"


End Sub
```

Comment: When I removed `objIE.Document.GetElementsByName("btnK").Click`, the Google page opened ok and the results for 'best radio' were displayed. I guess the problem lies their page being interactive and automatically changing from the home to the results page even before you hit 'Enter'. Thereby the `btnK` button is removed which you can then no longer click. That's why Excel fails.

Comment: How can I mark the tick for you? I can't find it.

Comment: You can't tick comments. I added an answer below, the tick mark is below the up / down arrows. Click the gray tick to mark the answer as accepted. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `objIE.Document.GetElementsByName("btnK").Click`. The Google page then opens ok and the results for 'best radio' are displayed.

**Explanation:** The problem lies in their page being interactive and automatically changing from the home to the results page even before you hit 'Enter'. Thereby the `btnK` button is removed which you can then no longer click (but are trying to). That's why Excel fails.

Comment: Can you solve the same question to a different site? Let's me post it. Hopefully, you can do it before others do. Good day!